# Disabling graphical login in Debian wheezy

Tags: debian, x11, startup, gdm, display-manager

I have installed Debian wheezy on my machine with a netinst image, now I would like to deactivate the desktop and boot straight to the command line, not only that but I would like to not waste any resource on the X11/gnome/gdm at all if not needed.

I tried ( as root )

```
update-rc.d -f gdm remove
update-rc.d -f gdm3 remove
update-rc.d -f wdm remove
```

but Debian keeps booting into the login manager, I really don't need that, how I can deactivate this kind of boot and start X only when needed ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look in `/etc/rc2.d/`. There are probably links to `/etc/init.d/xdm` and `/etc/init.d/kdm` which you haven't removed yet.

You can also edit the file `/etc/X11/default-display-manager`, which includes the full path to the default display manager Debian is using. If you replace the content of that file with `/bin/true`, you are probably disabling the start of any login-manager as well.

The TTYs are spawned anyways. If no login-manager is launched, TTY1 will remain the active TTY and you can just log in using the command line.

Comment: I'm sure i have no xfce or kde-related package installed because I just installed the "default" gnome desktop environment, I will go for `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` and see if this solves.

Comment: A quick `ls /etc/rc2.d/` would provide proof. I'm sure you have no idea what packages you never wanted have been installed. You're using Debian, not Gentoo. :-)

Comment: I commented out with a `#` the line inside `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` and added a new one with `/bin/true` and now it boots into a tty, or, in better terms, it doesn't boot any display manager, just like I wanted. Debian is my choice at the moment because of the really low requirements and the pre-compiled packages in the repository, I'm running it under an 800Mhz single core CPU with 128Mb of ram, to run Gentoo under this system you will need ages; but Debian is perfectly fine for now.

Answer (score 3):

For Debian 8 with systemctl:

```
systemctl disable gdm
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually for those who come across this looking how to disable login screen user list in Jessie the above comment about Debian 8 is incorrect at least as of today. To disable this in Debian 8 Jessie do the following:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults
```

With the file open remove the # in front of the disable-user-list=true line as shown in the file sample below.

```
# Login manager options
#======================
[org/gnome/login-screen]
logo='/usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/places/debian-swirl.png'
fallback-logo='/usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/places/debian-swirl.png'

# - Disable user list
# disable-user-list=true
# - Disable restart buttons
# disable-restart-buttons=true
# - Show a login welcome message
# banner-message-enable=true
# banner-message-text='Welcome'
```

After changing press 'CTRL+X' then 'Y' and press ENTER to save the changes.

After you save the file run the following command to restart GDM and you will be prompted for your login.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart gdm3.service
```