# Start from text mode + startx?

Tags: console, x-server, startx, trisquel

I'm trying to boot my Trisquel GNU/Linux distro directly from text mode, as I don't want to load the GUI if it's not necessary. I would like to work in tty1 until I type startx, which would start all the graphical stuff.

Is there a way to do it? I used to have Musix, and it worked fine, but it was a default config.

**INFO:**

Distro: Trisquel 7.0
GUI: GNOME 3.8.4

Comment: Did you search the [Trisquel](https://trisquel.info/en/forum/how-boot-terminal-only) [forums](https://trisquel.info/en/forum/booting-console-no-x)? Besides, trisquel 7 is based on Ubuntu 14.04, so most of the advice for Ubuntu 14.04 is valid for Trisquel.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86740/disabling-graphical-login-in-debian-wheezy) - since Trisquel is a second-generation Debian derivative, it could be all you need.